# mpicxx: Incompatible library version

Tags: c++, dll, mpi

I am trying to compile a c++ code to a dynamically linked library on my Mac v10.10

I run `wmake libso` in my directory where I have all my code.

and get the following readout:

```
SOURCE=gammaReThetatSST/gammaReThetatSST.C ;  mpicxx -m64 -fsignaling-nans  -ftrapping-math -DdarwinIntel64 -DWM_DP -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wold-style-cast -Wnon-virtual-dtor -O2  -DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -I/Users/oscarwilsby/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/turbulenceModels -I/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/transportModels -I/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude -I/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/meshTools/lnInclude -I/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/turbulenceModels/incompressible/RAS/lnInclude -IlnInclude -I. -I/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude -I/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude   -fPIC -Ddarwin -c $SOURCE -o Make/darwinIntel64GccDPOpt/gammaReThetatSST.o
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.8.4/lib/libopen-pal.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mpicxx
  Reason: Incompatible library version: mpicxx requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libopen-pal.6.dylib provides version 8.0.0
/bin/sh: line 1: 50563 Trace/BPT trap: 5       mpicxx -m64 -fsignaling-nans -ftrapping-math -DdarwinIntel64 -DWM_DP -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wold-style-cast -Wnon-virtual-dtor -O2 -DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -I/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/turbulenceModels -I/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/transportModels -I/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude -I/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/meshTools/lnInclude -I/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/turbulenceModels/incompressible/RAS/lnInclude -IlnInclude -I. -I/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude -I/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude -fPIC -Ddarwin -c $SOURCE -o Make/darwinIntel64GccDPOpt/gammaReThetatSST.o
make: *** [Make/darwinIntel64GccDPOpt/gammaReThetatSST.o] Error 133
```

Is this a matter of installing the correct version of some type of dependency? Please advise.

Edit:

I have already tried `brew update` followed by `brew unlink open-mpi` and finally `brew install open-mpi` but the problem persists. It may be worth pointing out that if I do `brew unlink open-mpi` then when I run `wmake libso` I now get some compiler errors:

```
/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/lduInterface.H:100:26: note: hidden overloaded virtual function
      'Foam::lduInterface::initInternalFieldTransfer' declared here: type mismatch at 2nd parameter ('const labelUList &'
      (aka 'const UList<label> &') vs 'labelUList &' (aka 'UList<label> &'))
            virtual void initInternalFieldTransfer
                         ^
gammaReThetatSST/gammaReThetatSST.C:240:24: error: conversion from 'tmp<GeometricField<double, fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh> >' to 'volScalarField'
      (aka 'GeometricField<scalar, fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh>') is ambiguous
        volScalarField magVort = sqrt(scalar(2))*mag(skew(fvc::grad(U_)));
                       ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/tmp.H:124:16: note: candidate function
        inline operator const T&() const;
               ^
/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/GeometricField.H:359:9: note: candidate constructor
        GeometricField
        ^
gammaReThetatSST/gammaReThetatSST.C:260:20: error: conversion from 'tmp<GeometricField<typename scalarProduct<SymmTensor<double>, Tensor<double>
      >::type, fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh> >' to 'volScalarField' (aka 'GeometricField<scalar, fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh>') is ambiguous
    volScalarField U2gradU = (sqr(U_)&&(fvc::grad(U_)));
                   ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/tmp.H:124:16: note: candidate function
        inline operator const T&() const;
               ^
/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/GeometricField.H:359:9: note: candidate constructor
        GeometricField
        ^
gammaReThetatSST/gammaReThetatSST.C:363:20: error: conversion from 'tmp<GeometricField<double, fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh> >' to 'volScalarField'
      (aka 'GeometricField<scalar, fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh>') is ambiguous
    volScalarField CDkOmegaPlus = max
                   ^              ~~~
/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/tmp.H:124:16: note: candidate function
        inline operator const T&() const;
               ^
/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/GeometricField.H:359:9: note: candidate constructor
        GeometricField
        ^
gammaReThetatSST/gammaReThetatSST.C:393:20: error: conversion from 'tmp<GeometricField<double, fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh> >' to 'volScalarField'
      (aka 'GeometricField<scalar, fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh>') is ambiguous
    volScalarField arg2 = min
                   ^      ~~~
/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/tmp.H:124:16: note: candidate function
        inline operator const T&() const;
               ^
/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/GeometricField.H:359:9: note: candidate constructor
        GeometricField
        ^
gammaReThetatSST/gammaReThetatSST.C:858:20: error: conversion from 'tmp<GeometricField<scalar, fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh> >' to 'volScalarField'
      (aka 'GeometricField<scalar, fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh>') is ambiguous
    volScalarField S2 = magSqr(symm(fvc::grad(U_)));
                   ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/tmp.H:124:16: note: candidate function
        inline operator const T&() const;
               ^
/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/GeometricField.H:359:9: note: candidate constructor
        GeometricField
        ^
gammaReThetatSST/gammaReThetatSST.C:864:20: error: conversion from 'tmp<GeometricField<scalar, fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh> >' to 'volScalarField'
      (aka 'GeometricField<scalar, fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh>') is ambiguous
    volScalarField CDkOmega =
                   ^
/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/tmp.H:124:16: note: candidate function
        inline operator const T&() const;
               ^
/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/GeometricField.H:359:9: note: candidate constructor
        GeometricField
        ^
gammaReThetatSST/gammaReThetatSST.C:895:20: error: conversion from 'tmp<GeometricField<double, fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh> >' to 'volScalarField'
      (aka 'GeometricField<scalar, fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh>') is ambiguous
    volScalarField gammaEff = max
                   ^          ~~~
/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/tmp.H:124:16: note: candidate function
        inline operator const T&() const;
               ^
/Users/ow222/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/GeometricField.H:359:9: note: candidate constructor
        GeometricField
        ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update libopen-pal

You can use homebrew `brew install open-mpi`

Comment: Thanks, can this be done in home-brew/ macports easily?

Comment: I would assume so.  You'd need to find which package owns it though

Comment: Its an answer.  Not a very complete one, but a start.  It is neither a critique or a request

Comment: @Outurnate Then please make it more complete, perhaps with instructions on how to update the library, and why you believe it is out of date. Shaiful's comment is a 'caned' response from the review queue, which indicates there is already at least one vote to delete your answer.

Comment: I tried `brew install open mpi`, but I get `Warning: open-mpi-1.8.4 already installed` So I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Yes I ran `brew update`, then `brew unlink open-mpi` followed by `brew install open-mpi` but the problem persists. Are you sure it is open-mpi which is the problem?